# Opening an link and scrape the data in exisiting webpage using selineum webdriver python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am learning web scraping using Selenium web driver using Python. For my learning purpose, I am scraping indeed.com. I am scraping job title, company name, location, salary and job summary. I can able to extract job title, company name, location, salary using beautiful soup. Job summary is loading into the next page where I am trying to using selenium to extract the data but not successful. I have checked all the posts here, but still couldn't able to do it. I can able to click the new page but I am not sure how to scrape the data from the new page.

my code

```
#Importing necessary library

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
import requests
from itertools import zip_longest
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

title = []
company = []
locations = []
summary = []

for pageno in range(0,26): 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://nz.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=New+Zealand&start=" + str(10*pageno))
    time.sleep(1)

    summaryItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'jobtitle turnstileLink')]")
    job_links = [summaryItem.get_attribute("href") for summaryItem in summaryItems]

    for job_link in job_links:
        driver.get(job_link)
        time.sleep(1)

        job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='icl-u-xs-mb--xs icl-u-xs-mt--none jobsearch-JobInfoHeader-title']").text
        title.append(job_title)

        company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='icl-u-lg-mr--sm icl-u-xs-mr--xs']").text
        company.append(company_name)

        location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='jobsearch-JobMetadataHeader-iconLabel']").text
        locations.append(location)

        job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='jobsearch-jobDescriptionText']").text
        summary.append(job_description)



driver.close()


# Converting all the details into dataframe and csv file
final = []
for item in zip_longest(title, company, locations, summary):
    final.append(item)

df4 = pd.DataFrame(
    final, columns=['Job_title', 'Company_name','Locations', 'Summary'])
#df.to_csv('booked.csv')


I tried to debug but not successful. One of the job page is not loading. I don't know the reason. Problem either 3 or 4 loop. Any suggestion?
```

I can able to click the new page but I am not sure how to scrape the data from the new page. I need to do for other pages as well automatically. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What errors you get?

Comment: @TeeKea I am not getting error. I don't know how to do it?

Comment: Well, you need to find the class, tag, or id names for the items you would like to collect the same way you did for getting the clickable item.

Comment: @TeeKea I can find the class name for the required data on the new page.     But, how to use the class name and scrape? example summary items have the old page and selenium open the new window using a summaryItem.click(). But how to scrape the new page with the class name? Sorry, If I am not clear.    Appreciate your help

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clicking to open a job on a new page, you can get the link of that job and load it again through Selenium, as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://nz.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist&l=New+Zealand&start=" + str(10*1))
time.sleep(5)

summaryItems = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'jobtitle turnstileLink')]")
job_link = summaryItems.get_attribute("href")
driver.get(job_link)
```

Now, you can easily get job information, as follows:

```
job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='icl-u-xs-mb--xs icl-u-xs-mt--none jobsearch-JobInfoHeader-title']")
company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='icl-u-lg-mr--sm icl-u-xs-mr--xs']")
location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='jobsearch-JobMetadataHeader-iconLabel']")
job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='jobsearch-jobDescriptionText']")
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get the information of all job listings, you can do so as follows:

```
summaryItems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'jobtitle turnstileLink')]")
job_links = [summaryItem.get_attribute("href") for summaryItem in summaryItems]

for job_link in job_links:
    driver.get(job_link)
    time.sleep(1)

    job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='icl-u-xs-mb--xs icl-u-xs-mt--none jobsearch-JobInfoHeader-title']").text
    company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='icl-u-lg-mr--sm icl-u-xs-mr--xs']").text
    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='jobsearch-JobMetadataHeader-iconLabel']").text
    job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='jobsearch-jobDescriptionText']").text
```

**EDIT 2:**

To avoid getting an error when there is no company name for a certain job, you can do the following:

```
try:
    company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='icl-u-lg-mr--sm icl-u-xs-mr--xs']").text
except:
    company_name = ""
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. When I tried to extract job title, I am getting this error "'WebElement' object has no attribute 'page_source'

Comment: I see. You can extract it using: `job_title.text `

Comment: Thanks @TeeKea . It's working. However, It's give for only one job ad, what I have to do for other jobs on the page. I am trying to add loop but it's not working.

Comment: I have updated my answer to help you make a loop that goes through all job listings. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: thanks for your support. It works. However, during one of the loop, I am getting the below error.

"Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='icl-u-lg-mr--sm icl-u-xs-mr--xs']"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)"
I am searching Data Scientist, New Zealand. Total 6 pages found.  My code in the above updated edit

Comment: I run it on my side and I get all pages until page 25 without any errors. Not sure what the problem is on your side. Maybe one of the jobs the company name is not present. Try to put the line where you get `company_name` in a `try:` block (you can search online how to do that). That should solve the problem. Also, you better move `driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())` before `for pageno in range(0,26):` the loop to get all pages processed in the same browser.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support. I tried with "try" and checked. Unable to find the error. So I manually did for each page and found out one of the company name pages is not loading. Then, I inspected the class for that particular company name and found everything is correct. Also, I moved the driver to the top as you advised but not successful. Could you please try my code one last time and check? I have edited my code again and changed the job into a data analyst from a data scientist. It has 26 pages.  If it works for you, then some problem in my driver I believe

Comment: I see your problem now. The company name may not exist for some jobs. I have edited my answer to show you how to avoid getting errors if there is no company.

Comment: are you there...?